# Editing a CSV file with weather data Bash shell .sh Script

Tags: bash

I would like to select the lower value from two temperature readings and insert it at "t:" in the CSV file. so just remove the higher of the two readings. this evaluation should be carried out individually for each line.

the file looks like this

```
{date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,00),t:2.4,t:18.4,t2:22.9,t3:24.2,t4:23.3,h:70,dp:12.8,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.0,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.2,wb:1.9,wr:316,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,10),t:18.1,t:23.2,t2:22.9,t3:24.2,t4:23.1,h:71,dp:12.8,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.1,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.1,wb:1.9,wr:316,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,20),t:17.9,t:23.2,t2:22.8,t3:24.2,t4:23.0,h:71,dp:12.6,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.2,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.3,wb:1.9,wr:316,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,30),t:17.7,t:23.2,t2:22.8,t3:24.1,t4:22.6,h:71,dp:12.4,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.1,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.7,wb:4.2,wr:6,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,40),t:17.6,t:23.2,t2:22.7,t3:24.1,t4:22.6,h:72,dp:12.5,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.1,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.1,wb:1.9,wr:59,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,50),t:17.4,t:23.2,t2:22.6,t3:24.1,t4:22.6,h:72,dp:12.3,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.1,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.5,wb:4.2,wr:59,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,01,00),t:17.3,t:23.2,t2:22.6,t3:24.1,t4:22.7,h:72,dp:12.2,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.2,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.6,wb:4.2,wr:28,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,01,10),t:17.2,t:23.2,t2:22.6,t3:24.0,t4:22.6,h:73,dp:12.3,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.4,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.0,wb:1.9,wr:20,},
```

The date doesn't matter because of the commas, after processing the csv file is loaded as a text file on my web server. Where it serves as a data source for an AmCharts 3 chart but i think CSV is better to manipulate than a .txt

Unfortunately, I don't know very much about Bash yet, but I imagine it like this:

```
Read .csv
count rows in .csv 
 $Rows = .csvRowsCount //get number of rows in CSV-File
do ($x = 1....$Rows) // counter loop for selecting the row
    if (row$x,col6 > row$x,col7) then {delete col6} // looks if col6 is higher than col7 when true then it   deletes (only in the $x row of the file)
    else {delete col7}
loop
```

This must be the output-File from the script (only the "t:" Values with the lower Values)

```
{date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,00),t:2.4,t2:22.9,t3:24.2,t4:23.3,h:70,dp:12.8,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.0,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.2,wb:1.9,wr:316,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,10),t:18.1,t2:22.9,t3:24.2,t4:23.1,h:71,dp:12.8,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.1,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.1,wb:1.9,wr:316,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,20),t:17.9,t2:22.8,t3:24.2,t4:23.0,h:71,dp:12.6,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.2,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.3,wb:1.9,wr:316,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,30),t:17.7,t2:22.8,t3:24.1,t4:22.6,h:71,dp:12.4,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.1,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.7,wb:4.2,wr:6,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,40),t:17.6,t2:22.7,t3:24.1,t4:22.6,h:72,dp:12.5,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.1,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.1,wb:1.9,wr:59,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,50),t:17.4,t2:22.6,t3:24.1,t4:22.6,h:72,dp:12.3,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.1,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.5,wb:4.2,wr:59,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,01,00),t:17.3,t2:22.6,t3:24.1,t4:22.7,h:72,dp:12.2,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.2,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.6,wb:4.2,wr:28,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,01,10),t:17.2,t2:22.6,t3:24.0,t4:22.6,h:73,dp:12.3,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.4,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.0,wb:1.9,wr:20,},
```

Is somewhere a live tryit Editor for Bash scripts? [Like this for Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ifthen)

[The AmCharts Graphs that need the Data](https://wetterstationwinkel.ch/Diagramme.php)

Comment: That's not CSV...

Comment: and that script is not bash.

Comment: Can you reduce the size of the data (once you know how to solve it 4 data points, changing *N* points won't be a problem. AND show your required output from that same, smaller sample data. 2-3 row, by 5-6 columns? .... As Is, I can't see what the change is that you've made. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
     { 
       # save column content to extra variable, remove leading "t:"
       c6=$6; gsub(".*:","",c6);
       c7=$7; gsub(".*:","",c7);
       # cast strings to numbers with +0
       if(c6+0 > c7+0)
         { $6="" };
       else
         { $7="" };
       # remove superfluous comma
       gsub(",+",",",$0);
       print
     }' file
```

Output:

```
{date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,00),t:2.4,t2:22.9,t3:24.2,t4:23.3,h:70,dp:12.8,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.0,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.2,wb:1.9,wr:316,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,10),t:18.1,t2:22.9,t3:24.2,t4:23.1,h:71,dp:12.8,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.1,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.1,wb:1.9,wr:316,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,20),t:17.9,t2:22.8,t3:24.2,t4:23.0,h:71,dp:12.6,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.2,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.3,wb:1.9,wr:316,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,30),t:17.7,t2:22.8,t3:24.1,t4:22.6,h:71,dp:12.4,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.1,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.7,wb:4.2,wr:6,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,40),t:17.6,t2:22.7,t3:24.1,t4:22.6,h:72,dp:12.5,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.1,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.1,wb:1.9,wr:59,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,50),t:17.4,t2:22.6,t3:24.1,t4:22.6,h:72,dp:12.3,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.1,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.5,wb:4.2,wr:59,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,01,00),t:17.3,t2:22.6,t3:24.1,t4:22.7,h:72,dp:12.2,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.2,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.6,wb:4.2,wr:28,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,01,10),t:17.2,t2:22.6,t3:24.0,t4:22.6,h:73,dp:12.3,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.4,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.0,wb:1.9,wr:20,},
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use awk instead:

```
awk 'function GSUB( F ){gsub(/t:/,"",$F);};  BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {GSUB(6); GSUB(7); if ($6 > $7){$7="";$6="t:"$6;}else{$6="";$7="t:"$7;}}1 gsub(/,,/,",")' f1.csv > f2.csv
```

However, you can also use bash if you really want to (e.g. if this question is actually part of a larger script). I would do something like the following:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 
  3 # Loop over each line in "f1.csv"
  4 # and put the line string into the "line" variable
  5 # Uses "read" and bash "redirection"
  6 while read line; do
  7   # "pipe" the line string into the "cut" utility and extract 
  8   # the 6th and 7th fields, using a comma as a delimiter
  9   # This could also be done in a single line.
 10   # The syntax $() called "command substitution"
 12   f6=$(echo $line | cut -f 6 -d ,)
 13   f7=$(echo $line | cut -f 7 -d ,)
 14   
 15   # Compare the floating point values using "bc"
 16   # We make use of bash "parameter expansion" here
 17   # to remove the "t:" from the beginning of each value
 18   if (( $(echo "${f6#t:*} > ${f7#t:*}" |bc -l) )); then
 19     # The 6th field is larger, so remove it from line
 20     # We use parameter expansion here as well to do this
 21     line=${line/$f6/}
 22   else
 23     line=${line/$f7/}
 24   fi
 25   # Remove duplicate commas from the line (probably should have done
 26   # this as part of the substitution on 21&23)
 27   # Then, append the new line to f2.csv using another redirection.
 28   # The >> here means append to file. 
 29   echo ${line/,,/,} >> f2.csv
 30 done < f1.csv
```

Both should do what you want:

```
$ cat f2.csv 
{date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,00),t:2.4,t2:22.9,t3:24.2,t4:23.3,h:70,dp:12.8,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.0,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.2,wb:1.9,wr:316,},
{date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,10),t:18.1,t2:22.9,t3:24.2,t4:23.1,h:71,dp:12.8,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.1,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.1,wb:1.9,wr:316,},
{date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,20),t:17.9,t2:22.8,t3:24.2,t4:23.0,h:71,dp:12.6,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.2,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.3,wb:1.9,wr:316,},
{date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,30),t:17.7,t2:22.8,t3:24.1,t4:22.6,h:71,dp:12.4,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.1,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.7,wb:4.2,wr:6,},
{date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,40),t:17.6,t2:22.7,t3:24.1,t4:22.6,h:72,dp:12.5,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.1,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.1,wb:1.9,wr:59,},
{date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,50),t:17.4,t2:22.6,t3:24.1,t4:22.6,h:72,dp:12.3,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.1,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.5,wb:4.2,wr:59,},
{date: new Date(2023,6,20,01,00),t:17.3,t2:22.6,t3:24.1,t4:22.7,h:72,dp:12.2,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.2,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.6,wb:4.2,wr:28,},
{date: new Date(2023,6,20,01,10),t:17.2,t2:22.6,t3:24.0,t4:22.6,h:73,dp:12.3,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.4,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.0,wb:1.9,wr:20,}
```

References for every bash concept I applied here:

1. [Pipelines (the "|")](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html)
2. [Bash Parameter expansion (things like the ${line/,,/,} commands, very powerful stuff in bash)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)
3. [Bash command substitution (the $() )](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)
4. [Redirections (The ">>" and "<")](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)
5. [The man page for "cut"](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html)
6. [The man page for "read"](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/read.1p.html)
7. [The man page for "bc"](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc)
8. [Bash looping constructs (the (( )) )](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still very inexperienced with Bash Shell, where exactly is the file read in in your example?

Comment: In both of the examples "f1.csv" is the input file and "f2.csv" is the output file. In the bash script, the file f1.csv is read using the bash "read" utility, but it actually appears at the closing "done" statement of the loop. It basically reads as "read each line from f1.csv, for each line, take columns 6 &7, compare them, remove the larger from the line, remove double commas, and append the resulting line to f2.csv"

Comment: Don't use all upper case variables in awk or shell to avoid clashing with built-in variables and obfuscating your code by making it look like you're using builtin variables. In your awk script `{...}1 gsub(/,,/,",")` would be clearer and more robust as `{...; gsub(/,,/,",")} 1`. Copy/paste your bash script into http://shellcheck.net and it'll tell you about some of the issues that script has.

Comment: That's super cool! Never thought there was, or that I would even look for, something like a linter for bash. you can even install that into your environment. You've filled a hole in my life I just realized existed.

Answer (score 0):

If your `t` fields are always field-6 and field-7 when considering the data as comma-separated, you can use `substr()` to isolate the values from each `t` field and then a simple comparison of the result to determine whether you need to remove field-6 or field-7 (a ternary is used below). Once you know which field to remove, `sub()` can be used to remove it without disturbing the format of the record, e.g.

```bash
awk -F, '{ a=substr($6,3); b=substr($7,3); n=((a+0)>(b+0))?6:7; sub(","$n,"")}1' tempdata
```

Above, `a` is the first `t:` temp, `b` is the second, `n` is the field to remove (either 6 or 7) which is removed with `sub()`.

**Example Use/Output**

With your sample temperature data in the file `tempdata`, you would receive the following:

```
$ awk -F, '{ a=substr($6,3); b=substr($7,3); n=((a+0)>(b+0))?6:7; sub(","$n,"")}1' tempdata
{date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,00),t:2.4,t2:22.9,t3:24.2,t4:23.3,h:70,dp:12.8,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.0,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.2,wb:1.9,wr:316,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,10),t:18.1,t2:22.9,t3:24.2,t4:23.1,h:71,dp:12.8,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.1,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.1,wb:1.9,wr:316,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,20),t:17.9,t2:22.8,t3:24.2,t4:23.0,h:71,dp:12.6,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.2,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.3,wb:1.9,wr:316,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,30),t:17.7,t2:22.8,t3:24.1,t4:22.6,h:71,dp:12.4,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.1,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.7,wb:4.2,wr:6,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,40),t:17.6,t2:22.7,t3:24.1,t4:22.6,h:72,dp:12.5,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.1,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.1,wb:1.9,wr:59,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,00,50),t:17.4,t2:22.6,t3:24.1,t4:22.6,h:72,dp:12.3,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.1,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.5,wb:4.2,wr:59,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,01,00),t:17.3,t2:22.6,t3:24.1,t4:22.7,h:72,dp:12.2,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.2,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.6,wb:4.2,wr:28,},
 {date: new Date(2023,6,20,01,10),t:17.2,t2:22.6,t3:24.0,t4:22.6,h:73,dp:12.3,f5:26,s:0,p:1014.4,r:0.0,st:0,w:0.0,wb:1.9,wr:20,},
```

That said, if what you are processing is part of a json file, then you should really use a json aware utility like `jq` instead of processing with shell tools. If not, `awk` is the natural choice for processing records (lines) of data - and there are many ways you can do it in `awk`.